# tab trigger not working for ultisnips

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-ultisnips

I have tried other solutions proposed of this question but still none of them worked.

Related config:

```
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
" Optional:
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = ['/home/ayush/.vim/bundle/ultisnips', '~/UltiSnips']
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
```

I use vundle package manager and installed ultisnips by `:PluginInstall`

When creating new snips, `:UltiSnipsEdit`, it opens a file at `~/UltiSnips/<language>.snippets`
and i think vundle installed the package at `~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips`.

Also,
`:verbose imap <tab>` 
shows

```
 <Tab>       * <C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>    
Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim                                                                                 Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and
`:help UltiSnips-snippet-search-path` shows 
`E149: Sorry, no help for UltiSnips-snippet-search-path`

If some more info is needed, please mention in comments.

Comment: You need to change the directories in `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` to the ones you installed with the plugin by Honza.

Comment: I didn't specified any folder, i just used `PluginInstall` which install in the default directory, `~/.vim/bundle/<plugin>` which i have specified. Am i missing something?

Comment: Read the document about the directories. I know the docs is huge, but most of it is just talking about the same thing over and over. So, just skim through it.

Comment: Start with a minimal vimrc and a test snippet. Run these [4 shell commands](https://0x0.st/zT64.txt).
The last one should start Vim in a buffer where `trigger` has been written; press Tab to expand the snippet.
If it's not expanded, something  is wrong  in your Vim  build (try  to recompile  a more recent version  with more  features), or  something is  wrong in  your UltiSnips plugin (make sure it's correctly installed), or something in your environment intercepts Tab before Vim.

Comment: If it is expanded, you have a working starting point.
From there, progressively re-include your custom Vim config and your snippets, until something breaks. When that happens, you'll have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post it here.

Comment: @user938271, Thanks for helping me out. It now works. You can make this as an answer. Also, what the last command does in those 4 commands that you linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` are used to search snippets, it's default to `['UltiSnips']`, there are 2 kinds of settings:

**relative path**

```
 let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = ['UltiSnips','foo']
```

UltiSips will loop each path in `runtimepath` to search for child directory named `UltiSnips` and `foo`, and use them as snippets source.

Note that "snippets" is reserved for snipMate snippets and cannot be used in
this list.

**absolute path, one entry only**

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = [$HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips']
```

UltiSnips will search snippets from and only from this directory.

Also check `:h UltiSnips-how-snippets-are-loaded` if you have doubts.

Your `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` are two absolute paths, it's a mistake.

Also note that `ultisnips` itself doesn't contain snippets, it doesn't have a `UltiSnips` child directory.

---

`g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` is your private snippets directory. But by default it's not defined.

```
g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir
                            Defines the directory where private snippet
                            definition files are placed in in.

                            As example, if the current 'filetype' is "cpp" the
                            :UltiSnipsEdit command looks for a file to edit in
                            this order:
                            1. An existing
                               g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir."/cpp.snippets" file
                            2. Find a matching "cpp" snippets file in
                               g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories
                            3. Create a new
                               g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir."/cpp.snippets" file
```

Don't mix up `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` and `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`.

---

**common setting**

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = $HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips'
```

Don't change `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`. UltiSnips will loop each path in your `runtimepath` to find subdirectory named `UltiSnips` as snippets source, when you call `UltiSnipsEdit`, it will open your private snippets if you already have one.

Note that `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` must be a child directory of one of  `runtimepath`.

Comment: I removed `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = ['/home/ayush/.vim/bundle/ultisnips', '~/UltiSnips']`  and added  `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = $HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips'`
Still tab is not working.

Comment: +1 It works now. Thanks